# Focus on Element in ngFor is off if large body of text

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm creating an FAQ chat system and each time a question is asked and answered it's added to an array so it displays in the chat window as a chronological conversation.

So for example:

```
Q0: Am I cool? 
A0: Yes!

Q1: Are you sure? 
A1: Yes I am!
```

When a new question is asked, if the body of the text is quite big I want to focus on the question asked so the user can read the start of the question and scroll down, reading the rest of the answer. So to this I implemented a `@ViewChild` that pulls the focus each time an item is added to the array.

```
@ViewChildren('questionDiv') questionDivs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

constructor() { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.questionDivs.changes.subscribe(() => {
        if (this.questionDivs && this.questionDivs.last) {
            this.questionDivs.last.nativeElement.focus();
        }
    });
}
```

Which does pull focus to div but not the top of it as seen here:
[image]

When I ask a question, this is the position I wish to see it in:
[image]

Here's my HTML/CSS just in case something in there is causing the issue:

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="!willobee && faqDisplay" class="faq-float faq">
  <img src="../../assets/willobee/general.gif" width="80" class="willobee-help" (click)="clearFaq()" >
  <div class="container faq-heading">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col"><h4>Need Help?</h4></div>
      <div class="col text-right"><i (click)="clearFaq()" class="fa fa-times close"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container faq-chat">
      <ngx-spinner 
      name = "faq"
      zIndex = 99
      size = "medium"
      color = "#FFFFFF"
      type = "ball-clip-rotate"
      [fullScreen] = "false">
      </ngx-spinner>
    <div class="row mt-2">
      <div class="col-lg-8 ml-3 faq-response" *ngIf="faqs.length > 0">
        <h5>Frequently Asked Questions</h5>
        <div class="faq-question"  
          *ngFor="let faq of faqs" (click)="showQuestionAnswer(faq)">
          {{faq.question}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 ml-3 faq-response">
        Still need help? Ask us a question!
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="selectedFaq" class="ml-auto mr-3 faq-user">
        {{selectedFaq.question}}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="selectedFaq" class="col-lg-8 ml-3 faq-response">
        {{selectedFaq.answer}}
      </div>
      <div tabindex="1" #questionDiv class="faq-item" *ngFor="let faq of faqsAnswered">
        <div *ngIf="faq.question" class="ml-auto mr-3 col-lg-8 faq-user">
          {{faq.question}}
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="faq.answer" class="col-lg-8 ml-3 faq-response text-justify">
          {{faq.answer}}
          <p *ngIf="!faq.feedbackProvided && faq.correlationId !== '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'" class="mt-3 faq-helpful text-right">Was this answer helpful? <br /> <i class="fa fa-check mr-3 text-light" (click)="provideFeedback(true)"></i> <i class="fa fa-times text-light" (click)="provideFeedback(false)"></i></p>
          <p *ngIf="faq.feedbackProvided && faq.correlationId !== '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'" class="mt-3 faq-helpful text-right">Thank you for your feedback!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 ml-3 faq-response" *ngIf="faqs.length > 0">
          <h5>Frequently Asked Questions</h5>
          <div class="faq-question"  
            *ngFor="let faq of faqs" (click)="showQuestionAnswer(faq)">
            {{faq.question}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group input-group-md">
    <input autocomplete="off" list="autocompleteOff" (keyup.enter)="askQuestion()" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ask me a question..." aria-label="Ask" [(ngModel)]="userQuestion" id="userQuestion" name="userQuestion">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button id="user-btn" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" (click)="askQuestion()">Ask</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.faq-float {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.willobee-float {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 75px;
    right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.willobee-help {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: -25px;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.faq {
    width: 450px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 44px -11px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 44px -11px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 44px -11px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.faq-chat {
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.faq-chat::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.faq-chat::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.faq-chat::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #222222;
}

.faq-heading {
    color: #FEFEFE;
    padding: 1em 1.4em 0.6em 1.4em;
}

.faq-response {
    background: lightslategrey;
    color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.faq-question {
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.faq-user {
    background: whitesmoke;
    color: lightslategray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    /* margin: 10px 0; */
}

.faq-helpful {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
} 

.faq-item {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest `scrollIntoView` instead of `focus`. Focus is meant more for form controls.

```
this.questionDivs.last.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
```